# What is the right way to commit only certain changes in git?

Tags: git

When I work on multiple files, sometimes I work on different features corresponding to different files.

What I usually do is:

```
git status
git add <file/directory 1> # eventually with /* following directory name to commit
                           # the subdirectories rather than the directory itself
                           # (not sure how it works exactly)
git add <file/directory 2>
git commit -a              # here add commit message in editor
[ ... after N commits ... ]
git push (origin master / whatever)
```

What I noticed is that **most times** it just works: the committed files are exactly the ones I added. Some times, though, it commits **all** the files.

Am I doing it wrong?

Also, what's the difference between **commit -a** and **commit -m**?

Comment: Have you considered reading the man page or documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you commit, you are committing only *what has been staged* to be committed. To stage something for commit, use `git add`.

```
$ ls
file1 file2 file3

$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1
    modified:   file2
    modified:   file3

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Here, we have three files, all of them modified. But say we only want to commit `file1` and `file3`.

```
$ git add file1 file3

$ git commit -m 'my commit message'
[master 7c43d4b] my commit message
 2 files changed, 2 deletions(-)
```

The commit is complete, but `file2` was left as-is, and not committed.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file2

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When you use the `-a` flag to `git commit`, you are telling it to first add *everything* that has been changed, and then perform a commit. This can be a useful command, but it doesn't seem to be what you're looking for here. It is roughly equivalent to

```
cd /base/of/repository
git add .
git commit
```

(Side note: `git commit -a` will only add changes to tracked files. If you have a file in `.gitignore` or untracked files, those changes are *not* staged.)

It is important to realize that `git add` stages *changes to content*, which is not always the same thing as *files*.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file2

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git add file2

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   file2

$ echo "foobar" >> file2

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   file2

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file2
```

Here, we started out with a modified `file2`, then used `git add` to stage it. After that point, it shows up as being ready for commit. Then, we change the file *again*. Now, it has some changes staged for commit, but other changes that are not staged. If we commit right now,

```
$ git commit -m 'my commit message'
[master 4342cdc] my commit message
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)

$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file2

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

We have committed the staged changes, but the ones that were not staged are still sitting there waiting for us to handle them. *Both in the same file.*

This makes committing in git extremely flexible, although it has a tendency to confuse people.

You may also want to read up on `git add -p`, which is a way to stage only part(s) of the changes to a file. I frequently use this to stage changes but to hop over various notes and junk I've left in the file and not cleaned up yet.

Answer (score 4):

`git commit -a` is your problem. `git commit -a` adds all file modifications and commits them. `-a` and `-m` are very different flags; `-m` lets you type in a message on the command line. `man git-commit` or `git commit --help` will show you what the flags mean.

Comment: so, how do I commit only certain changes with one commit message associated to them?

Comment: just commit one file adding that specific file, committing that file with a specific message using -m "personalized message for a specific change on a specific file" and the git push

Comment: and to commit **multiple** files but **not** all? (that was the main point)

Comment: @dragonmnl: Use `git add <file>` to add the files you want, then `git commit` (or `git commit -m <msg>`) to commit them.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb and the proper way:

`git status` to see which files have yet to be committed 
`git add -A` to add all uncommitted files **or**
`git add yourFileName` 
**then**
`git commit -m "your message"` 
**followed by** 
`git push`

Comment: so, if do git add file1, git add directory2 etc. + commit -m should do the trick?

Comment: No, as far as i'm concerned, you'd have to use the -a